# Sequelize TypeError: Cannot read property 'max' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm not sure if the instance is not being created correctly or not but my model seems to be undefined. Here's how my code is setup:

db.js

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const basename = path.basename(module.filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
const config = require(__dirname + "/config.js")[env];
const db = {};

if (config.use_env_variable) {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable]);
} else {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.database,
    config.username,
    config.password,
    config
  );
}

fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, "models"))
  .filter(function(file) {
    return (
      file.indexOf(".") !== 0 && file !== basename && file.slice(-3) === ".js"
    );
  })
  .forEach(function(file) {
    let model = sequelize["import"](path.join(__dirname, "models", file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`Connection was successful!`);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(`Unable to connect to database: ${err}`);
  });

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = {
  db
};
```

Manifest.js (in models folder)

```
"use strict";

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  let Manifest = sequelize.define("Manifest", {
    manifestNumber: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(10),
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    huller: DataTypes.STRING(50),
    address: DataTypes.STRING(50),
    carrier: DataTypes.STRING(50),
    driver: DataTypes.STRING(50),
    dateShipped: DataTypes.DATE,
    preparedBy: DataTypes.STRING(15),
    recievedBy: DataTypes.STRING(15),
    truckLicenseNumber: DataTypes.STRING(25),
    frontTrailerLicenseNumber: DataTypes.STRING(25),
    rearTrailerLicenseNUmber: DataTypes.STRING(25),
    splitLoad: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    tagNumber: DataTypes.STRING(50),
    grossTotal: DataTypes.DECIMAL(18, 0),
    netTotal: DataTypes.DECIMAL(18, 0),
    totalBins: DataTypes.DECIMAL(18, 0),
    phase: DataTypes.STRING(10),
    shipments: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    submitDate: { 
      type: DataTypes.DATEONLY, 
      defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
      allowNull: false 
    }
  });

  return Manifest;
};
```

api.js (snippet)

```
const db = require("../db");
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/manifests/new", function(req, res) {
  let manifest = req.body;

  db.Manifest.max("manifestNumber")
    .success(max => {
      if (max) {
      // Convert max to int, add 1, then post with new manifest
      } else {
      // Empty table so start with 1
      }
    })
    .error(err => {
      console.log(`Error querying max: ${err}`);
    });
})
```

I made sure that the file name matches exactly what's defined in the model, but I'm not sure if that matters when my db.js reads through the models directory and adds it to the db variable. Could it be the way my code is structured or that I'm misusing db when I include it in my api.js? I know that this code is connecting to my SQL Server instance correctly, but could it be that this model is not linking to the existing table correctly? Or that the table happens to be empty at this moment? Any and all help is much appreciated by this Sequelize noob!

Comment: Actually, the issue was simply that I exported db in an object instead of just itself. Changing it to just module.exports = db fixed it. Silly me.

Answer (score 0):

In Sequelize you don't need to put all models in a variable...
When you use `sequelize.import` automatically you will have the `sequelize.models` (array of all models imported from your model folder) and the `sequelize.model` function and you must use something like this: `sequelize.model('Manifest')`

db.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = ({ logger, config }) => {
  config.db.logging = (
    config.db.logging !== false
      ? query => logger.debug('[DATABASE]', query)
      : false
  )

  const db = new Sequelize(config.db)

  loadModels(db)

  Object
    .keys(db.models)
    .forEach((model) => {
      if ('associate' in db.model(model)) {
        db.model(model).associate()
      }
    })

  return db
}

// ===============================================

function loadModels (sequelize) {
  const dir = path.join(__dirname, 'models')
  fs.readdirSync(dir)
    .forEach(
      file => sequelize.import(path.join(dir, file))
    )
}
```

I don't have any consistency in my `loadModels` function because all files in the model folder must export a sequelize model.

About your error. Check if your `Object.keys(db)` really have your models, because your `readdirSync` seems to be wrong. So check that.

Comment: So I commented out everything in forEach() and console logged modelName and get Manifest. It seems to be getting the correct name at least, but db[modelName] seems to be an empty object. Also, you're right about the consistency tidbit, the tutorial I followed had it in an index.js in the models folder but I thought I could just do it in my db.js file instead.

Comment: @JulianToyaAngeles check before this... maybe your sequelize.import returns undefined for some reason.